# JSF commandButtons both open separate window, but only one should

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

The following two command buttons both open a second browser, but I only have the `onclick` target `_blank` on the second button.  The unexpected behavior appears by clicking the second <kbd>View Report</kbd> button and then clicking the first <kbd>Update Chart</kbd>:

```
<h:form>
  <h:commandButton value="Update Chart" action="#{commitment.loadChartData}" />&nbsp;
  <h:commandButton value="View Report" action="#{ccommitment.generateReport}" onclick="this.form.target='_blank'" />
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you click second button it will set `target` property of the `form` object. This property will stay `_blank` and it will be applied on the first button click. You can reset this property in `onclick` of first button.

Comment: doh!  I guess I didn't realize it was setting it on the whole form. So putting onclick="this.form.target='_self'" on the other button works.  Thanks.

Comment: I was just double checking it worked in my real code. sorry for the delay.